# Django: add a DEFAULT class into input/select fields

Tags: python, django

What I need to is just **add a default class I'll call "myclass"** to all input/select fields appearing into add/edit forms. I want to transform this

```
<div class="field-label">
<div>
<label for="id_label" class="required">Label:</label>
<input type="text" name="label" id="id_label" class="vTextField">
</div>
</div>
```

Into this

```
<div class="field-label">
<div>
<label for="id_label" class="required">Label:</label>
<input class="myclass" type="text" name="label" id="id_label" class="vTextField">
</div>
</div>
```

I know that this output is done into fieldset.html template (admin/includes/fieldset.html) but I **have no clue where field.field parameter is set and how**, since is clearly already formatted:

```
[... ]
    {% if field.is_checkbox %}
        {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {% if field.is_readonly %}
            <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
        {% else %}
            {{ field.field}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
[...]
```

Where can I edit that?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is a way to set default classes for inputs from Django. You should have a look at [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms).

It will let you customize your form straight from your Form class. So, in the template you only have to add `{% crispy some_form %}`

Comment: Thank you zubhav for clearifying this, your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can replace {{field.field}} with something like this:

```
<input id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
                     name="{{ field.html_name }}"
                     value="{{ field.value }}"
                    {% if field.field.max_length != None %}
                        maxlength="{{ field.field.max_length }}"
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if field.field.min_length != None %}
                        minlength="{{ field.field.min_length }}"
                    {% endif %}
                     >
```

This should allow you to put the class you want on your inputs =)